# Radio Button not holding value after saved

Tags: wordpress, radio-button

I have an options panel for Wordpress. I have some radio buttons that work perfect. But when I click radio button 2 and save it then it goes back to 3? 
The weird thing is that is echos 2 in my theme? Any suggestions?

```
<label for="Slider_Shadow_Type">Slider Shadow</label>
<br />
<input name="Slider_Shadow_Type" checked="checked" type="radio" value="None"  >
<br />
<input name="Slider_Shadow_Type" checked="checked" type="radio" value="Shadow 1"  >
<br />
<input name="Slider_Shadow_Type" checked="checked" type="radio" value="Shadow 2"  >
<br />
<input name="Slider_Shadow_Type" checked="checked" type="radio" value="Shadow 3"  >
<small>Select the shadow style.</small><div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are all set to checked, so it will revert to the last one in the list, i.e. 'Shadow 3'. remove the 'checked="checked".